# Destruir(Logout) Session_ID Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Através do código abaixo eu recupero todos os usuários logados no sistema e os exibo numa tabela.

```
<?php
        $dados = array(
            'session_id',
            'ip_address',
            'last_activity',
            'user_data'
        );
        $this->db->select($dados);
        $query = $this->db->get("ci_sessions");        
?>
```

---

```
<tbody>
  <?php foreach ($query->result() as $linha):?>
     <tr>
     <?php
    $sessao = $linha->user_data;
    $dados = unserialize($sessao);
     ?>
     <?php if(!empty($dados['nome_usuario'])): ?>
     <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($dados['nome_usuario'],ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?></td>
     <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($linha->ip_address, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
     <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s',$linha->last_activity);?></td>
     <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('login/deslogar'); ?>" 
          class="btn btn-danger btn-flat">
     <?php echo lang('usuarios_deslogar_usuario'); ?></a></td>
     <?php endif; ?>
     </tr>
  <?php endforeach;?>                                   
</tbody>
```

---

O que eu quero agora, é ter uma opção de deslogar usuário para cada linha exibida, que quando clicado, o usuário seja deslogado.

Através do botão:

```
<td>
  <a href="<?php echo site_url('login/deslogar'); ?>" 
          class="btn btn-danger btn-flat"><?php echo 'Deslogar'; ?>
  </a>
</td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Então, como faço para destruir somente a sessão do `id` que ***desloguei***?

Comment: Já fiz isso, e fiz passando o session_id e removia essa linha do banco de dados, assim, qdo esse usuário tentava fazer qualquer outra ação no site ele era redirecionado para a tela de login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisa criar um método e excluir o registro desse usuário pelo `session_id` da tabela `ci_sessions`:

***`Html`***

```
<td>
  <a href="/login/deslogar/<?php echo $linha->session_id;?>" 
          class="btn btn-danger btn-flat">Deslogar</a>
</td>
```

---

***`Controller`***

```
public function deslogar($id)
{
    $this->db->where('session_id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('ci_sessions');   
}
```

A próxima ação do usuário, o mesmo será direcionado para fazer login novamente, isso impede que ele trabalhe na última sessão, mas, não na criação de uma nova, isso pode ser feito também com um campo `status` ou `active`.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Database Driver - Sessions](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver)
- [How I can set a session in codeigniter 3 database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086348/how-i-can-set-a-session-in-codeigniter-3-database)
- [Query Builder Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)
- [Deleting Data](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#deleting-data)

Comment: Obrigado!, Funcionou para mim.